# Not able to change Bootstrap CSS with ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sure there are multiple ways of accomplishing this and I'm open to any suggestions but at the moment I'm trying to find a way to dynamically change a Bootstrap alert based on the CSS I'm passing in the ViewBag.

When I try the following it doesn't display the Bootstrap alert at all. Basically what I'm looking to do is have a generic alert at the top of a View. Then I'll look at the ViewBag for a message and if that is not Null I will display it. If it's displayed I would like to look at the CSS so that way I can either pass an error message or a success message. I can see the ViewBag results with the following code but it doesn't show the Bootstrap alert at all.

This is in the Controller

```
ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Just testing.";
ViewBag.ResultMessageCss = "alert-danger";
```

This is in my View

```
@if (ViewBag.ResultMessage != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible @ViewBag.ResultMessageCss;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&close;</button>
        @ViewBag.ResultMessage;
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is going to render the below HTML.

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger;">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">close</button>
     Just testing.;
</div>
```

The last CSS class name you have is `alert-danger;` That is not a valid bootstrap class name. It should be `alert-danger`. So if you remove the unnecessary semicolon, it will properly render the bootstrap message box.

```
@if (ViewBag.ResultMessage != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible @ViewBag.ResultMessageCss">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">close</button>
        @ViewBag.ResultMessage
    </div>
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, that was it. I was totally over looking the semi-colon inside the DIV tag. Took a couple minutes to see it even with your explanation. Thanks!